# PowerMockito Mocking whenNew not taking effect

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

**Description:**

I cannot seem to have my stubs or mocks take affect in the class I have under test. I am trying to use the whenNew action so I can mock a return object and then mock a operation on that object with a returned value.

I imagine its something simple I am missing but not seeing it.

SOLUTION: Originally I was running with `MockitoRunner.class` and it required being changed to `PowerMockRunner.class`. Code below reflects the solution.

Jars on the classpath:

- powermock-mockito-1.4.11-full.jar
- mockoito-all-1.9.0.jar
- javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
- junit-4.8.2.jaf
- objensis-1.2.jar
- cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar

**TEST CLASS**

```
   import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
    import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(ClassA.class)
    public class ClassATest {

        @Test
        public void test() throws Exception
        {
                String[] returnSomeValue = {"PowerMockTest"};
                String[] inputValue = {"Test1"};
                ClassB mockedClassB = mock(ClassB.class);
                whenNew( ClassB.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn( mockedClassB );
                when( mockedClassB, "getResult", any(String[].class) ).thenReturn(returnSomeValue);       

                IClassA classUnderTest = new ClassA();
                String[] expectedValue = classUnderTest.runTest(inputValue);      
        }

    }
```

**Class A Implementation**

```
public class ClassA implements IClassA {

    @Override
    public String[] runTest(String[] inputValues) {

        String[] result;
        IClassB classB = new ClassB();
        result = classB.getResult(inputValues);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using powermock features (`@PrepareForTest`, `PowerMockito.whenNew` etc.), you have to run your test with the PowerMockRunner.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

Because ClassB#geResult is not private, you may also simplify your code and replace

```
when( mockedClassB, "getResult", any(String[].class) ).thenReturn(someValue);
```

by

```
when(mockedClassB.getResult(any(String[].class))).thenReturn(someValue);
```

Comment: Tried that and it fails on the any(String[].class) ) saying "misplaced argument matcher detected here. Seems like its very hard to pass an array when mocking.

Comment: I dont understand, it works in my environment.Try with this also : "when(mockedClassB.getResult(any(String[].class))).thenReturn(someValue);"

Comment: I complete my answer. Please complete your question by providing some details on your environment : junit, powermock, powermockito and mockito versions. Provides also the value of someValue in ClassATest#mockingTest.

Comment: I deleted all everything and started fresh and resolved the issue I was having. Updated description to show root issue, resolution and additional configuration.