# Mocking a local object inside a method of SUT using Mockito or PowerMocktio

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I've class method like below which creates a local object and calls a method on that local object.

```
public class MyClass {
    public someReturn myMethod(){
        MyOtherClass otherClassObject = new MyOtherClass();
        boolean retBool = otherClassObject.otherClassMethod();
        if(retBool){
            // do something
        }
    }
}

public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public testMyMethod(){
        MyClass myClassObj = new MyClass();
        myClassObj.myMethod();
        // please get me here.. 
    }
}
```

When I'm testing `myMethod`, I want to mock `otherClassObject.otherClassMethod` to return something of my choice. otherClassMethod does some class to Message Queues and I don't want that in Unit test. So I want to return true when I do otherClassObj.otherClassMethod(). I know I must have used a factory for `MyOtherClass` instantiation in this case but it's legacy code and I don't want to change any code now. I see that Mockito doesn't provide this facility to mock `MyOtherClass` in this case but possible with PowerMockito. However, I could not find an example for above scenario but found only for static class. How should I mock local object inside a method of SUT ?

I also referred to some other OS questions like - [Mocking methods of local scope objects with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520242/mocking-methods-of-local-scope-objects-with-mockito) but they were not helpful.

A code example will be of great help.

Comment: You could use reflections to do that.

Comment: Hold on; from your sample code your `otherClassObject`'s invocation is completely ignored. Is your sample code incomplete or couldn't you just mock the results of `myMethod`?

Comment: @fge, I updated my code and question.

Comment: And what do you want to test exactly from `myMethod()` here? I don't really see what you are after...

Comment: @fge there is much code after retBool in myMethod. I did not place all that here. My question is - how to mock otherClassObject in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using PowerMockito you can use the `whenNew` method

It should look something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)  //tells powerMock we will modify MyClass to intercept calls to new somewhere inside it
public class MyClassTest{

    @Test
    public void test(){
          MyOtherClass myMock = createMock(MyOtherClass.class);
          //this will intercept calls to "new MyOtherClass()" in MyClass
          whenNew( MyOtherClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn( myMock) );
          ... rest of test goes here

   }
```

Also this other SO post has example code too [PowerMockito Mocking whenNew Not taking affect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957485/powermockito-mocking-whennew-not-taking-affect)

Comment: the other SO post link made everything clear. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is not a real answer but with PowerMockito you can do this:

```
final MyOtherClass myOtherClass = mock(MyOtherClass.class);
// mock the results of myOtherClass.otherClassMethod();

PowerMockito.whenNew(MyOtherClass.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(myOtherClass);

// continue with your mock here
```

Now, not sure whether you actually need the result of this otherClassMethod here, but if you don't, I'd suggest you mock the results of `myMethod()` instead -- unless `myMethod()` is what you want to test because this other method has an influence on it, and yes, in this case a refactoring should be considered... And not delayed ad vitam aeternam...